# Openshift spring boot deploy fails

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

I am deploying a simple spring boot application in open shift
But fails after build success.

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springdemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add tomcat only if I want to run directly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>springdemo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

AppMain

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {


    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(){


        return "Spring Boot running......";
    }
}
```

all this on git when I start pulling from OpenShift it build success but after get error and not deployed.

I have selected Java and Redhut jboss(tomcat 8)

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:15.524s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Mar 04 12:24:08 UTC 2017
/usr/bin/mvn: line 9:    33 Killed                  $M2_HOME/bin/mvn "$@"
Aborting due to error code 137 from Maven build

error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver30-tomcat8-openshift@sha256:727603994024d133ead698832e07xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: What is the result of `oc describe pod <failed-build-pod>`? You can also check `oc get events` to see what has happened in the project itself.

Comment: Almost looks as if the build round out of memory but would expect a different error. Do you have any additional logs or events, like bibix suggested describing the builder pod will be good.

Comment: same error I got using codecentric/springboot-maven3-centos docker

Answer (score 0):

Check the resources tag in the build yaml file. 
If not add resources like below

```
resources:
limits:
  cpu: '2'
  memory: 2Gi
requests:
  cpu: '1'
  memory: 1Gi
```